# CSS space between space when line return not working

Tags: css

I would like to set the space between span lines to 15px but it doesn't work when i'm using line-height and i measuring the space with chrome extension the space it's not equal to 15px.

```
<div class="test">
<span style="line-height:15px;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
</span>
</div>
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbueL.png)

Comment: spaces btw the 2 base lines is indeed 15px;

Comment: Enclose each section in `<p>` tags and just say `p{margin-bottom:number px;}`.

Comment: it should be less than the normal or default by 1 px because default line height is 1em which is 16px in most defaults .

Comment: The line height is 15px as stated earlier. From where to where are you measuring? `line-height` in CSS is not the same as a typographical leading and is centered around the text itself. It is also unaffected by font size if you use px.

Comment: @aeid : no the spacing is 8px like you can show in picture and not 16px

Comment: its actually more than 16px its `1.2 * 16 px` depending on browser and font family ?

Comment: your code is working,

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for. I have added a p element so CSS would recognize this block of text.

```html
<div class="test">
<span>
  <p style="line-height:25px;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  </p>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: hi thank you for your help but i talk here about the space when return to line inside the same <p> or <span> and not the space between span or p

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working. Remember that line-height doesn't affect the font-size but the effective spacing before and after the text (which is why the DOM viewer in chrome shows that the height hasn't changed).

Here is a snippet to highlight what is going on.

```css
.test {
   background-color: blue;
}

.test > span {
   line-height: 125px;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working . you just probably are measure wrong.

```
<div class="test" style='width:50px'>
  <span style="line-height:1; font-size:15px">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  </span>
</div>
```

line-height will take values without units as a multiple of the font size. 
it is the space each line takes .

Answer (score 0):

Line boxes "belong" to the containing block element - in your case the `.test` element, and inline elements like your span are broken into multiple inline boxes across the line breaks and the parts are then fitted into the line boxes.

So on each line of the `.test` element, there's a zero-width inline box called a  [`strut`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#strut) and a part of the span. The span has a line-height of 15px, but the strut has a line-height determined by the `.test` element.

Since you're not change the font family, or font sizes, or vertical alignments, the distance from the top of one line to the next is simply the maximum of the line height of the strut and the line height of the span.

The default font size, font-family, and line-heights will give a line height of the strut to be around 18 to 19 pixels, hence why you are seeing bigger gaps than you expect.

So to reduce the space between the lines, reduce the strut's line-height as well as the span's line-height, which you do by setting the line-height for the containing block. The span element can then just inherit it. i.e. Use:

```css
body { width:200px; } /* for demo to make multiple lines */

.test {
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
</span>
</div>
```